# Cannot find module '@nuxt/cli'

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I keep getting

> Cannot find module '@nuxt/cli'

Whenever run `npx nuxt generate`.

although 
`npm i nuxt-cli`
 is already installed

Answer (score 1):

For projects with [VUE-CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html):

***npm install -g @vue/cli***

If you want to create a new project with [NUXT](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/commands) you need:

***npx create-nuxt-app your-project-name***

Once you have your project ready. If you want to generate your web application into static files you can make use of:

***npm run generate***

I believe you maybe have a little mix-up between NUXT and VUE-CLI and their commands. Check the documentation of [NUXT](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/commands) and [VUE.JS](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html)

Comment: I follow your guide, but when running `npx create-nuxt-app your-project-name`, I got error `Trace: { Error: Cannot find module './prompts'`, any idea?

Comment: Are you creating a NUXT or VUE-CLI project? 
Your npm version is superior to 5.2.0?
Can you share the settings of your workspace to have an idea?

Comment: @Yuci fix for /prompts was released, try again

Comment: Glad to hear Yuci!